# HTML width property does not work in Markdown

Tags: html, markdown

I am creating a table using HTML in Markdown.

The code is

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:2px;text-align: center;background: #2c3e50;" ><font face="youyuan">Column1</font></th>
<th style="width:150px; text-align: center;background: #c3e50;"  ><font face="youyuan">Column2</font></th>
<th style="text-align: center;background: #2c3e50;"  ><font face="youyuan";>Column3</font></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
...
</tbody>

</table>
```

Other parameters like `background`, `text-align` work as expected. However, the column length does not change at all. Three columns are equaly seperated. Why the `width` does not work here and how to address this issue?

Comment: because the content is to wide and the cell would overflow. Therefor it will be ignored and resized to allow the content to fit the cell. If you really want to limit a with of a column to 2px, use `max-width`.

Comment: Hi @tacoshy Thanks for your reply~. It was 20px and I just want to test if this works... However, I modified all `width` to `max-width` but still no change..

Comment: it does, check the size of the background color, it just overflows the cell then and messes up the design completely. To allow the content to fit within 20px you need to declare a wordbreak (wordwrap) so that the content will be smaller. tables have their limitations, also a reason why they shouldnt be used for design purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table cell has by default no overflow with a scroll ability. Therefor the default behavior will cause a cell to resize accordingly to allow the content to actually fit the cell. If you remove the content `Column1` then you see, that the cell only has a width of your declared 2px. Without content the cell wouldnt overflow and as such can size at 2px.

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width: 2px; text-align: center; background: #2c3e50;"><font face="youyuan"></font></th>
<th style="width:150px; text-align: center;background: #c3e50;"  ><font face="youyuan">Column2</font></th>
<th style="text-align: center;background: #2c3e50;"  ><font face="youyuan";>Column3</font></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
...
</tbody>

</table>
```

You can use `max-width` to force a cell to only have the given width. You can see that the width then is applied if you compare the background color. Also the cell-content now collide and clearly proof that the first cell only has the given max-width. However since a table cell does not wordbreak nor gets a scrollbar, the content will collide with each other and appear messed up.

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="max-width: 20px; text-align: center; background: #2c3e50;"><font face="youyuan">Column1</font></th>
<th style="max-width:150px; text-align: center;background: #c3e50;"  ><font face="youyuan">Column2</font></th>
<th style="text-align: center;background: #2c3e50;"  ><font face="youyuan";>Column3</font></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
...
</tbody>

</table>
```

There is nothing wrong with HTML in this case nor with the table, but the logic to fit a larger content into a smaller container. A table is not meant for such purpose as it also is not ment for styling just holding and display data in a table format. For styling purpose you have css-grid.